# Windows 10 "Microsoft account needs attention" error pop-up

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, microsoft-account, microsoft

I have a user who just got issued a new computer and at least once a day you gets a notification that says his Microsoft account needs fixing/attention. When we go into email and accounts in the settings his email says "needs attention" in the bottom right hand corner. We click his account, hit fix and then it says update was successful and he's good until the next day when he logs in.

What we've tried:

- Turning off shared experiences
- Turning off notifications for Microsoft accounts (Microsoft Accounts wasn't even there as an option)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I see this occasionally (Windows 10 and 11).  But not frequently if fixed. Maybe try uninstalling Office, then restart and install Office again. See if that helps.

Comment: Would you think repairing it might work too? I didn't even think of that

Comment: A repair might work.  Try and if not , then reinstall.

Comment: An online repair seems to have done the trick! The user restarted and logged in and didn't get the pop-up, thank you!